# Is there a way to tell GCC the range of a parameter?

Tags: gcc, optimization

I have some heavily-used code that I would like GCC to optimize aggressively. But I also want to write clean, reusable code with (inlinable) functions that are called from several places. There are cases where in the inlined function, there is code that I know can be removed because the conditions can never happen.

Let's look at a concrete example:

```
#include <assert.h>

static inline int foo(int c)
{
  if (c < 4)
    return c;
  else
    return 4;
}

int bar(int c)
{
  assert(c < 2);

  return foo(c);
}
```

With `-DNDEBUG -O3`, GCC will still generate the (c < 4) comparison even though I know it is not needed, because a precondition of the `bar` function is that `c` is 0 or 1. Without `-DNDEBUG`, GCC *does* remove the comparison because it is implied by the asserts - but of course you have the overhead of the asserts then (which is a lot more).

Is there a way to convey the variable range to GCC so it can be used for optimisation?

If CLang can do better on this, I could also consider switching compilers.

Comment: Clang 4.0 / Zapcc do slightly better than GCC 7.1 - 4 instructions instead of 5 on x64 - but neither are clever enough to opt out foo's  `c < 4`. You can check this with various compilers at https://godbolt.org/g/3Hp4ZA, none of which I checked were able to optimize this (which makes sense). Ideally there would have been some magical pragma for specifying a range for c in bar, but I don't think anyone had come up with such pragma just yet... Or perhaps some smart assert builtin, that could remove itself from the generated code, yet be recognized by the optimizer.

Comment: @Mike: the asserts are just an example, I'll just remove the first one since it's not relevant here (not used in optimisation).

Comment: @valiano: indeed, a smart assert is what I am looking for. GIMPLE (GCC's internal representation) keeps track of variable ranges, that's how it can optimise away the (c < 4) in case the asserts are there. I'd like a way to express such ranges explicitly instead of just letting the compiler do the analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use `__builtin_unreachable` (read about [other builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html)) in a test to tell the compiler, e.g.,

```
if (x<2 || x>100)
    __builtin_unreachable();
// Here the compiler knows that x is between 3 and 99 inclusive
```

In your case, add this at the start of your `bar` (probably wrapped in some nice looking macro):

```
if (c >= 2)
    __builtin_unreachable();
```

If you optimize strongly (e.g., [-O2](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-O2) at least), the compiler *knows* that *x* is between 3 and 99 (and recent versions of GCC contain code to do such analysis—at least processing *simple* constant interval constraints like above—and take advantage of them in later optimization passes).

However, I am not so sure that you should use that! (at least don't use it often and wrap that in some `assert`-like macro), because it might not worth the trouble, and because the compiler is in practice only able to handle and propagate *simple* constraints (whose details are compiler version specific).

As far as I know, both recent [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) and GCC accepts that builtin.

Also look into `__builtin_trap` (which also emits runtime code).

Comment: I was about to post that. You can wrap it in a macro: `#define ASSUME(COND) do { if (!(COND)) __builtin_unreachable(); } while (0)`

Comment: Works like a charm! Why, however, do you say not to use it?